# stopUpdateLocation() doesn´t work swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit, updating

when I perform my segue, the location is still updated in the next VC. I tried to put the startUpdatingLocation() into an other function than the super view, but nothing changed. Do you have any ideas what i can do? Grüße aus Mannheim

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class uploadPrepare: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate,    CLLocationManagerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var weiterButton: UIButton!

let locationPrepare = CLLocationManager()

var regionPrepare: MKCoordinateRegion!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationPrepare.delegate = self
    locationPrepare.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationPrepare.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationPrepare.startUpdatingLocation()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func weiterButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){

    self.locationPrepare.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMapCheck", sender: self)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let locationPrepare = locations[0]
    let myLocationPrepare:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationPrepare.coordinate.latitude,locationPrepare.coordinate.longitude)
    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0005,0.0005)
        regionPrepare = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocationPrepare,span)

    print("\(locationPrepare.coordinate.latitude)")

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    let uploadInterfaceGoing = segue.destination as! mapCheck
    uploadInterfaceGoing.regionReceived = regionPrepare   
}

}
```

Comment: Actually, CLLocationManager would still callback several times after called stopUpdatingLocation() function. The latest location is the most accurate one. If you want to stop calling `didUpdateLocations` immediately, just set `self.locationPrepare.delegate = nil` after stopUpdatingLocation.

Comment: hmm it still updates the location

Comment: i put sender to Any and it worked. thanks